# TFS 2008 apply label with C#

Tags: c#, label

Is there a way to apply a label to a TFS 2008 project/directory with C#?
I know of the command line program:

```
tf label SampleLabel $/Project1/Source/* /recursive /server:TFS1
```

But i want to do this with C# code, and do NOT want to run TF.exe commandline from C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code snippet labels all changes in a particular changeset.  It should be straightforward to change it to label all files in a particular path.  Instead of iterating through the changeset, just do a `vcServer.GetItems("$/Project1/path", RecursionType.Full)` and iterate through them.

```
    private void LabelChangeset(string fileLabel, Changeset changeset)
    {
        VersionControlLabel vcl = new VersionControlLabel(vcServer, fileLabel, null, cbProjects.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Autogen label.");

        LabelItemSpec[] itemSpecs = new LabelItemSpec[changeset.Changes.Length];

        string ver = string.Format("C{0}", changeset.ChangesetId);
        VersionSpec fileVersion = VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(ver, null);

        int index = 0;
        foreach (Change c in changeset.Changes)
        {
            itemSpecs[index++] = new LabelItemSpec(new ItemSpec(c.Item.ServerItem, RecursionType.None), fileVersion, false);
        }

        LabelResult[] results = vcServer.CreateLabel(vcl, itemSpecs, LabelChildOption.Replace);
    }
```